# Как избежать дублирования кода в сервисном слое?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, инспекция-кода

```
public interface IOperationService
{
    IEnumerable<OperationItem> GetItems(int operationId);
}

public class OperationService: IOperationService
{
    public IEnumerable<OperationItemViewModel> GetItems(int operationId)
    {
        var items = getItems(operationId);
        //дальнейшие действия по преобразованию
        //OperationItem в OperationItemViewModel
    }
    private IEnumerable<OperationItem> getItems(int operatonId)
    {
        return _context.Set<OperationItem>().Where(x=>x.OperationId==OperationId)
               .Include(x=>x.File)
               .ToList();
    }
}
```

где

- `OperationItem` - класс доменной модели;
- `OperationItemViewModel` - вью модель

Весь этот код у меня находится в сервисном слое.

Мне потребовалост добавить новый *сервис* `IAssemblyService` в котором на текущий момент будет только один метод: `IEnumerable<AssemblyViewModel> GetAssemblies(int operationId)` а проблема заключается в том что для этого мне необходимо получить список итемов входящих в указанную операцию и для этого мне необходимо иметь доступ к методу `getItems()` из `OperationService`. Хочется избежать дублирования и оставить интерфейс чистым. Подскажите как лучше всего это реализовать?

**UPD**: можно попрбовать сделать так:

```
public IEnumerable<AssemblyViewModel> GetAssemblies(int operationId)
{
    var items = (OperationService)_operationService).getItems(operationId);
    //дальнейшие действия
}
```

но я не уверен в *правильности* данного способа

Comment: Если у вас один сервис зависит от другого, то он должен быть обычным клиентом для условно "стороннего" сервиса.

Comment: @Monk если честно то совсем не понял

Comment: Как снаружи запрашивается `IOperationService.GetItems(...)`, так и ваш новый `IAssemblyService` должен запрашивать их.

Comment: @Monk так проблема то в том что `getItems` & `GetItems` возвращают разные коллекции: первый возвращает экземпляры DAO, с навигационными свойствами и прочим, а второй уже для отображения пользователю

Comment: Если технически это не один сервис, то придется делать метод публичным и запрашивать снаружи. Если один - то делайте внутренний метод и используйте в обоих сервисах.

Answer (score 2):

Шаблон репозиторий вообще один из самых проблемых ([раз](http://blog.byndyu.ru/2011/01/domain-driven-design-repository.html), [два](http://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern/), [три](http://blog.byndyu.ru/2011/08/repository.html)...).
Как у витязя на распутье у вас есть три пути:

- Вызывать из одного репозитория другой. Но это превратит код в паутину.
- Отнаследоваться. Это приведет к огромным God-object'ам.
- Поменять архитектуру приложения. На давно существующем проекте крайне рискованная операция.

Как видите все варианты достаточно негативные: «Направо пойдёшь – коня потеряешь, себя спасёшь; налево пойдёшь – себя потеряешь, коня спасёшь; прямо пойдёшь – и себя и коня потеряешь».

Пожалуй, я бы в итоге порекомендовал текущие приложения не менять -- но читать больше про архитектуры приложений. Domain Driven, Data Driven, CQRS.
Сложно рекомендовать книги и статьи, не зная, что ваш текущий уровень, но попробую:

- http://blog.byndyu.ru/2014/07/command-and-query-responsibility.html
- https://habrahabr.ru/post/313110/
- https://habrahabr.ru/post/259829/
- https://habrahabr.ru/post/158277/

Comment: спасибо большое за приведенные ссылки