# Onion архитектура asp.net mvc core приложения

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, архитектура, asp.net-core

Я сделал небольшое приложение с, как мне кажется, нормальной многослойной архитектурой. https://github.com/Kunoichi/AST Подскажите пожалуйста, может я что-то делаю не так? Может есть какие-то более хорошие подходы.

Есть несколько вопросов:

1. Не слишком ли много бизнес логики в моих контроллерах?
2. Имеет ли смысл делать статические репозитории и статический UnitOfWork, которые будут использовать ссылку на объект DbContext для работы? Или лучше чтобы они были объектами?
3. Если ли смысл в методе Dispose класса UnitOfWork? Я сделал его по примерам из интернета, но Dispose у меня нигде не используется. Если его нужно использовать, то где и зачем?
4. Как я понял, я использую антипаттерн Generic-repository. Чем плохим это может грозить в будущем?
5. У приложений всегда должен быть только один контекст базы данных или сколько угодно? (имею в виду как будет грамотнее с точки зрения проектирования приложений)

Comment: Архитектура часто зависит от поставленной задачи, потому сложно что то сказать. Разве что логирования я у вас не заметил (может пропустил). Основной вопрос - если вы что то не используете в своем коде, зачем оно тогда там находится?

Comment: Архитектура диктуется задачей, а вы ищете удобную универсальную архитектуру, которую будете в любую задачу шлёпать, не вдумываясь, насколько она подходит. Многослойных архитектур много, вы нащупали одну из очевидных. Хотите потренироваться в ней -- добро, просто не думайте, что ваш подход будет применим в любой задаче. Вот если даже не уходить от репозиториев, посмотрите сколько [ньюансов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/659578/213987). Отдельная тема "анемичные модели". Многие из ваших вопросов если начать копать глубоко -- вы будете тут же уходить в другие архитектуры.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В данный момент существует множество подходов к созданию архитектуры MVC приложений (*Domain Driven Design, 3d-layered architecture, onion structure, etc*).

Мой любимый подход это 3х уровневая архитектура и вот почему:

1. Позволяет легко избавиться от зависиомтей используя Inversion of Control
2. Каждый из уровней отвечает за свои задачи, что позволяет придерживаться принципа Single responsibility даже на уровне слоя.

Приложение ASP.NET MVC с этим подходом выглядело бы так:

1. **Data layer** - библиотека, которая организовывает связь с базой данных, в неё входят UoW, Repository pattern, EF если имеется и Data models
2. **Bussiness layer** - библиотека отвечающая за сервисы, бизнес логику и DTO (data transfer objects которые связывают Data Models и View Models)
3. **Presentation layer** -  собственно сам MVC, сюда входят ViewModels, View, Controllers, конфигурация IoC и т.д.

Благодаря такой архитектуре изменения в одном уровне не повлекут за собой огромных изменений (а при правильном построении SOLID вообще не изменят другие слои).

Теперь по поводу реализации и вопросов:

1. Контроллеры должны быть по принципу as thin as possible и любая бизнес логика в них говорит о том что реализацию можно улучшить и всю логику можно и нужно выносить в сервисы. В вашей реализации присутствует обработка изображений, которую по хорошему следует вынести в отдельный сервис назвав его ImageManipulationService и убрать из контроллеров **#helpers**
2. Любую статику очень сложно покрыть тестами в будущем, лучше всего придерживаться реализации этих паттернов как объектов - в будущем будет намного легче поддерживать приложение.
3. Интерфейс IDisposable специально был разработан для высвобождения ресурсов, которые не будут уничтожены Garbage Collector`ом (в основном это касается unsafe кода), в реализации UoW считается хорошей практикой высвобождать DbContext перед уничтожением самого UoW, так что паттерн реализован хорошо.
4. Использование Generic Repository довольно распространенная практика и это намного лучше чем писать под каждую сущность новый объект репозитория. Не вижу никаких проблем использовать этот паттерн.
5. У приложения может быть несколько контекстов базы данных в случае если приложение использует несколько БД одновременно. На практике такое случается крайне редко и если это вопрос по поводу реализации общего интерфейса для DbContext то это скорее overengeenering чем хорошая практика.

PS. Под Generic Repository хорошо подходит реализация Generic UoW:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable  
{
    T GetRepository<T>() where T : class;
    int Save();
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork  
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> _repositories;
    private IDbContext _dbContext;

    public UnitOfWork() : this(new AppContext())
    {
    }

    public UnitOfWork(IDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _repositories = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Search for repository in dictionary and if not exists creating new.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of repository to create.</typeparam>
    /// <returns>Returns repository with DbContext provided by UoW.</returns>
    public T GetRepository<T>() where T : class 
    {
        if (!_repositories.ContainsKey(nameof(T)))
        {
            var repository = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), _dbContext);
            _repositories.Add(nameof(T), repository);
        }

        return (T)_repositories[nameof(T)];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves all pending changes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The number of objects in an Added, Modified, or Deleted state</returns>
    public int Save()
    {
        return _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes current object.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_dbContext != null)
            {
                _dbContext.Dispose();
                _dbContext = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

2.
Во-первых, `DbContext` сам по себе является и репозиторием и единицей работы. Поэтому делать обёртки поверх него нет смысла. Имхо.

Статический UnitOfWork? Это как вообще? Смысл этого паттерна в том, что создаётся юнит, выполняется какая-то работа, закрывается юнит, что приводит к сохранению (или откату) данных, освобождению занятых ресурсов и т. п. То есть он никак не должен быть статическим.

3.
Как уже сказано выше, единица работы должна создаваться и удаляться по ходу работы. Реализовав интерфейс `IDisposable`, можно использовать удобную конструкцию `using`, что приведёт к закрытию юнита даже в случае исключений.

Но, как я уже сказал, `DbContext` не нуждается в обёртках.

5.
Их может быть сколько угодно. Например, один контекст может быть для работы с данными пользователей сайта, другой - для админов. Однако, чем их больше, тем тяжелее писать, а главное - поддерживать код.

Сделав несколько контекстов, намного сложнее осуществлять миграции! Спасибо tym32167 за напоминание.

Comment: Поправка: репозиторием является DbSet, а не DbContext

Comment: Имеет смысл делать репозитории отдельно от контекстов если репозиторий использует несколько источников данных или нужна возможность смены уровня работы с данными.

Comment: Имея несколько контекстов к одной БД, в теории можно получить проблемы с миграциями.

Comment: @tym32167 - про миграции верно. Я когда пробовал несколько контекстов ввести, в итоге отказался именно из-за проблем с миграциями.

Comment: Создание своей обертки над EF позволяет мне отказаться от него при необходимости. В своих приложениях я не удаляю записи, а лишь помечаю их как удаленные. Методы репозиториев возвращают false при ошибке добавления, удаления и тд, нет необходимости использовать try-cath в сервисах. Без лишней обертки пришлось бы проверять статус удаления элементов и отлавливать ошибки/исключения при работе с бд в сервисах. Я не вижу смысла уничтожать, а затем заново создавать UOW в другом методе, а скорее всего именно так и выйдет, если использовать `using`.

Comment: @mirypoko - вам виднее. Но статический UoW, по-видимому, означает, что он существует всё время работы приложения? А если дисконнект произойдёт, по таймауту, например?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov об этом я не подумал. По идее при таймауте будет выкинуто исключение на уровне репозитория и вызванная из сервиса функция вернет false.

Comment: На тему "создание своей обёртки над EF". Отвыкайте делать эти лишние обёртки. Все проблемы могут быть решены путём введения дополнительного слоя абстракций, кроме одной. (С) Есть холиварная тема: юзать log4net или NLog, так вот есть любители создать абстрактный логгер, чтобы проще перейти с одного логгера на другой. Понимаете, к чему я клоню? Вы на каждую использованную библиотеку не хотите создать по обёрточке? А если вы не захотите менять EF на что-то другое? На старте создали пять обёрток, а поменяли одну, зачем оверхед на старте проекта? Надо будет -- поменяете. "Если" (с) лаконцы

Comment: @AK хм, я любитель добавлять интерфейс для логгера. И дело даже не столько в том, чтобы иметь возможность логгер сменить, сколько в том, что я хочу процесс логгирования контролировать, контролировать АПИ для логгирования, доступный клиентскому коду, и, по необходимости, добавлять свою логику. Не вижу тут проблем :) А вот с репозиторием да, не все так однозначно