# Репозиторий "два-в-одном"

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, репозиторий

Есть некоторый сервис, который дёргает два репозитория (первый - к сущности Order, второй - к сущности OrderPosition) и возвращает уже собранный заказ - Dto объект, в котором лежит и Order и OrderPosition.

```
public async Task<OderDto> DetailsAsync(int orderId)
{
    var order = await this.OrderRepository.GetAsync(orderId);

    var orderPositions = await this.OrderPositionsRepository.ForOrderAsync(orderId);

    return new OrderDto
    {
       Order = order,
       OrderPosition = orderPositions,
    };
}
```

Так было устроено приложение, когда оно было собрано на чистом EF - клепаешь себе простенькие Linq-выражения, живёшь не нарадуешься.

Однако когда-то наступает момент, когда некоторые запросы становятся сложными и в приложении появляется Dapper c plain sql запросами. Допустим тот же пример очень хочется переписать избежав двух запросов к базе, всё за раз. И, вместо соединения данных в сервисе прямо в репозитории достаём то, что нам надо:

```
public async Task<OderDto> GetOderDtoAsync(int orderId)
{
    const string query = @"
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.Order o
        WHERE 1 = 1
            AND o.Id = @orderId

        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.OrderPosition op
        WHERE 1 = 1
            AND op.OrderId = @orderId
    ";

    var parameters = new
    {
        @orderId = orderId,
    };

    using (var multi = this.Db.QueryMultiple(query, parameters))
    {
        var order = await multi.ReadSingleOrDefaultAsync<Order>();
        var orderPositions = await multi.ReadAsync<OrderPosition>();

        return new OderDto
        {
            Order = order,
            OrderPosition = orderPositions.AsList().AsReadOnly(),
        };
    }
}
```

(Сервисы конечно в таком подходе редко нужны - только для какой-то сложной обработки выбранных данных, чаще просто излишний слой, тупо передающий данные as is. Но эта экономия числа запросов к базе очень сильно подкупает, да и [подобных проблем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654682/213987) уже не возникает.)

Вопрос чисто методологический. Можно ли при этом продолжать считать, что используется шаблон Repository или это уже не репозиторий?

У меня так выходит, что это класс совмещает в себе два репозитория и некоторую логику (характерную для сервиса) над возвращёнными объектами, а значит (несмотря на всю дырявость паттерна репозиторий) надо дать ему более подходящее название. Но какое? На что вообще похож данный подход в построении приложения?

Comment: Не очень понял. Если контракт класса не поменялся, назначение класса не поменялось, то какая разница как именно класс делает то, что делает?

Answer (score 1):

Репозиторий - это вполне конкретный паттерн.

Точнее, два разных паттерна:

1. [Классический репозиторий из PoEAA](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). Тот самый, который Mediates **between the domain and data mapping layers** using a **collection-like interface** for accessing domain objects.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ваш код не предоставляет доступ доменным объектам в виде коллекции (вы же какие-то DTO наверх выдаете) - значит, это не Repository.

2. "Репозиторий запросов", который в C# обычно проявляется в виде класса-обертки поверх готовой реализации репозитория (1) в EF, и которы обычно используют ради возможности подменить его на мок при юнит-тестировании BL, и заодно ради предотвращения прорастания IQueryable выше в BL.

У него вроде бы нет определения в каком-нибудь PoEAA, но общий смысл примерно "Инкапсулирует в себе построение LINQ-выражений, изолирует IQueryable от сервисного уровня, позволяя написать на сервисный уровень юнит-тесты". Тоже не ваш случай.

Т.е. у вас был класс, который назывался "Repository", но на самом деле это было обычный Transaction Script с прямой выборкой данных внутри - и вы просто переписали эту выборку данных. Репозитория, в строгом смысле, у вас не было и нет. И он вам, скорее всего, не нужен.

Comment: Я как раз на сервисном уровне и пишу тесты, для этого собственно мне и нужно абстрагирование от слоя базы.

Comment: @AK да, дело просто в том, что у вас не DDD как Фаулер завещал (сервисы именно как уровень для управления транзакциями, вся логика в классах доменной модели, репозиторий именно для представления объектов в виде коллекции), а простой не-DDD подход - анемик модель-дто ([что плохо, не DDD и вообще антипаттерн по Фаулеру](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)) + transaction script в виде "сервисов" с логикой в них + "репозиторий запросов". Просто подход к разработке приложений поменялся, DDD в его "чистом" виде не прижилось, и все делают как проще, а не как "правильно"

Comment: @AK простой пример - если у вас микросервис или какой-то web api - то вы вполне можете положить метод GetOderDtoAsync прямо в контроллер - и все будет отлично работать. Это не означает, что класс контроллера станет репозиторием + контроллером + сервисом 3-в одном. Это просто означает что у вас обязанности между классами не разделены - а суть паттерна репозиторий именно в выделении конкретной обязанности, а не в "где написан вызов Dapper - там и репозиторий".